# Is ionic better option for developing mobile apps?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-mobile, ionic-framework

There is lot of confusion what to use, which framework most of the developers are using?. What is in demand for mobile app development??

should i start to learn Ionic and start working on projects based on it. 
or
i should go for angular Material or Jquery Mobile or any other frame work.

if am using ionic, do i need to use bootstrap?

what is the future (framework) for mobile app development or which should i go for? 
please suggest me what should be better to go for if am looking for mobile app development sector?

Comment: I'd reccommend doing a little research before asking such a broad question on SO. That being said, check out articles on quora digest for ionic2, react native and nativesript. Those are currently the three contenders in the fornt-end mobile app world with ionic and react leading the latter. Ionic worked with the Angular2 team and react is backed by FB so I imagine both are going to be around for quite some time, it's merely your preference and what your familiar with at this point.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi, I am using Ionic 1/2 because i like angular lot rather then jquery
> but i will suggest you to go with ionic because ionic 2 and angular 2
> are ready to use in development so it is good to work on new
> technology rather then old one like jquery mobile and framework 7
>
> check this link for better explanation

http://www.findalltogether.com/post/comparing-the-best-hybrid-app-frameworks-ionic-vs-f7-vs-famous-vs-onsenui-vs-manifoldjs/

Answer (score -1):

Yes if you going for the hybrid app then Ionic is really better. Otherwise think about the same app need to be develop for different platform individually .